# Compiling all OSM data with the Key:Wheelchair

Tags: openstreetmap, query, definition-query

I want to analyze the data coverage of wheelchair data in OSM.

Therefore I want to compare the ratio of all OSM data that has the Key:wheelchair and if the data is tracked or not.

I am looking for an OSM query that gets me every OSM data that with the Key:wheelchair.

I know that the key is tracked for data according to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:wheelchair. However, the Wiki only lists examples of where wheelchair data is tracked.

I was wondering if someone knows how to query a comprehensive list for all data that tracks the key.

Comment: On the linked [wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:wheelchair) there is a link to overpass, where you can run a query for wheelchair like https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1we6 - it returns all objects (in current bounding box) with `wheelchair` tag.